Introduction to solana-program
Please I'm new to this. I need someone to explain how this solana works. I've tried creating a solana stake exchange account but it doesn't seem to work

Please be more specific. If you post your stake exchange program code and the error that you're facing, we'd be happy to help you.

There are various ways to get started and learn about Solana. I would recommend starting with tutorials
getting start

learn about blockchain fundamentals https://solana.com/learn/blockchain-basics
set up your Solana environment https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/setup-local-development

courses

Solana BootCamp - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLilwLeBwGuK6NsYMPP_BlVkeQgff0NwvU

SolDev - https://www.soldev.app/course

Calyptus Curriculum - https://learn.calyptus.co/learn-solana/


ref - https://solana.com/developers
communities

The 76 devs - https://discord.gg/VSwCNPyW

solanaU - https://discord.gg/solanau

solana Tech - https://discord.gg/solana


feel free to use this site to ask technical questions
